# store user input without mysql or php

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html application which displays words on a click of a next button. It fetches the words from a javascript object literal file. I want to mark some of the words as easy and some as difficult. How do I save this data from browser without using a mysql database?
can I edit the javascript object file directly from bowser?

Comment: you will need server-side no doubt. But you can give a try to html5 local storage or clientSide database, that works entirely with javascript but be aware that it is not widely supported yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take user input and store it permanently on your site, you'll have to employ some sort of server-side scripting.  This doesn't have to be PHP, but it's probably the simplest way to do it.  You can't use client-side javascript to write to a remote file directly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have JS object/array with words, you're modifying it and want to store it modified version permanently.

If so, then you can use ["HTML5" `localStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

This storage is per-browser. If you want to have single version shared between many users/browsers, then you will need some server-side support.

Answer (score 0):

To save it on the client-side you could use cookies or local storage on supported browsers but this may not be the best approach if there are many words to keep track of.